# Formula for matrix (dates in descending order)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

As a sequel to this question [Formula for matrix (dates in ascending order)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/164682/290090)  how would the formula (`=IF($B2="Apple",A2-SORT(FILTER(A:A,B:B="Pear", A:A<$A2),1,FALSE),"")` be modified if the dates are in descending order?

That is, Tony ate an apple on some day, how many days before did he eat a pear?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 changes, those in red/bold :

[image: changes]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. In future, kindly post code, it's easier to copy-paste

Comment: I could not do it, since it is not possible to highlight those 3 parts in red

Comment: Got it thanks...